# Xcode fail to build my project

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm a very newbee in iOS computing and  i appologize for this...

So, i created a cross platform project (android / iOS) with Windev Mobile 20 from PCSOFT. It runs fine in android, but i can't manage to build it with xCode.

At the first time, the build succeeded but there was a warning :

> Warning: Error creating LLDB target at path '/Users/jeanbiasotto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECONAUTE-cspaqjjoybpnbjgjitexfqycmrku/Build/Products/Release->iphonesimulator/ECONAUTE.app'- using an empty LLDB target which can cause slow >memory reads from remote devices.

I found a fix on stackoverflow by modifying architecture to Standard architecture(armv7,arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD).

Then new errors appeared and it seems that Linker failed... :

> Ld /Users/jeanbiasotto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECONAUTE-cspaqjjoybpnbjgjitexfqycmrku/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/ECONAUTE.app/ECONAUTE normal x86_64    cd /Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
>      export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.plat>form/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/>local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>
> > /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/>usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/D>eveloper/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -L/Users/jeanbiasotto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECONAUTE-cspaqjjoybpnbjgjitexfqycmrku/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -L/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib -F/Users/jeanbiasotto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECONAUTE-cspaqjjoybpnbjgjitexfqycmrku/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -F/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib -filelist /Users/jeanbiasotto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECONAUTE-cspaqjjoybpnbjgjitexfqycmrku/Build/Intermediates/ECONAUTE.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ECONAUTE.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECONAUTE.LinkFileList ->mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc->link-runtime -framework AddressBook -framework MobileCoreServices -framework >CoreGraphics -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework >MediaPlayer -framework AVFoundation -framework UIKit -framework AddressBookUI ->framework CoreFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework QuartzCore ->framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMedia -framework ImageIO -framework >MessageUI -framework Foundation -framework CoreText -framework MapKit -liconv.2 >-lwd200vm -lwd200obj -lwd200mat -lwd200xml -lwd200grf -lwd200hf -lwd200std ->lwd200com -lwd200sql -lwd200pnt -lwd200core -lwd200mdl -Xlinker ->dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/jeanbiasotto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECONAUTE-cspaqjjoybpnbjgjitexfqycmrku/Build/Intermediates/ECONAUTE.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ECONAUTE.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECONAUTE_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/jeanbiasotto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECONAUTE-cspaqjjoybpnbjgjitexfqycmrku/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/ECONAUTE.app/ECONAUTE
>
> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200vm.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200vm.a (3 slices)
>   ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200mat.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200mat.a (3 slices)
>   ld: warning: ignoring file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200obj.a, missing >required architecture x86_64 in file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200obj.a (3 slices)
>   ld: warning: ignoring file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200xml.a, missing >required architecture x86_64 in file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200xml.a (3 slices)
>   ld: warning: ignoring file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200grf.a, missing >required architecture x86_64 in file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200grf.a (3 slices)
>   ld: warning: ignoring file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200hf.a, missing >required architecture x86_64 in file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200hf.a (3 slices)ld: >warning: 
>   ignoring file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200std.a, missing >required architecture x86_64 in file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200std.a (3 slices)
>   ld: warning: ignoring file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200com.a, missing >required architecture x86_64 in file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200com.a (3 slices)
>   ld: warning: ignoring file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200sql.a, missing >required architecture x86_64 in file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200sql.a (3 slices)
>   ld: warning: ignoring file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200pnt.a, missing >required architecture x86_64 in file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200pnt.a (3 slices)
>   ld: warning: ignoring file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200core.a, missing >required architecture x86_64 in file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200core.a (3 slices)
>   ld: warning: ignoring file >/Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200mdl.a, missing >required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/jeanbiasotto/Documents/ECONAUTE.xcode.gen/lib/libwd200mdl.a (3 slices)
>   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>    "InitModule(_stMyModuleInfo const*)", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in >WDAppDelegate.o
>    "LoadWDLFile(NSString*)", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in >WDAppDelegate.o
>    "OBJ_InitIOS(UIWindow*, bool)", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in >WDAppDelegate.o
>    "InitInstance()", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in >WDAppDelegate.o
>    "InitAppLaunchOptions(NSDictionary*)", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in >WDAppDelegate.o
>    "InitInternalLanguage(int)", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in >WDAppDelegate.o
>    "ExecDidEnterBackground()", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground:] in WDAppDelegate.o
>    "ExecWillEnterForeground()", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate applicationWillEnterForeground:] in WDAppDelegate.o
>    "OBJ_SendApplicationDidBecomeActive()", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] in WDAppDelegate.o
>    "OBJ_SendApplicationWillResignActive()", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate applicationWillResignActive:] in WDAppDelegate.o
>    "InitExec()", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in >WDAppDelegate.o
>    "TermExec()", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate applicationWillTerminate:] in WDAppDelegate.o
>    "_gstMyModuleInfo1", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in >WDAppDelegate.o
>    "_gstMyModuleInfo10", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in >WDAppDelegate.o
>    "_gstMyModuleInfo28", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in >WDAppDelegate.o
>    "_gstMyModuleInfo3", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in >WDAppDelegate.o
>    "_gstMyModuleInfo4", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in >WDAppDelegate.o
>    "_gstMyModuleInfo6", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in >WDAppDelegate.o
>    "_gstMyModuleInfo61", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in >WDAppDelegate.o
>    "_gstMyModuleInfo68", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in >WDAppDelegate.o
>    "_gstMyModuleInfo7", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in >WDAppDelegate.o
>    "_gstMyModuleInfo70", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in >WDAppDelegate.o
>    "_gstMyModuleInfo8", referenced from:
>        -[WDAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in >WDAppDelegate.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm completely lost... I don't know where to search...

Some help will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Did you check the library you are using has the support to run on simulator? as x86_64 refers to simulator builds..

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `Build Active Architecture Only` to NO

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer zylenv, unfortunately, this action doesn't change anything...